# Two table join using laravel

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel 4.2. I want to join two tables. It is throwing an error. I don't see where I made a mistake.

```
$players = DB::table('orders_items')
        ->join('users', function ($join) use ($order) {
            $join->on('users.user_id', '=', 'orders_items.user_id')
            $join->on('users.state', '=', 'countries_states.state_id')
                 ->where('orders_items.order_id', '=', $order->order_id);
        })
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that You should move `where` method outside the function:

```
$players = DB::table('orders_items')
    ->join('users', function ($join) use ($order) {
        $join->on('users.user_id', '=', 'orders_items.user_id');
        $join->on('users.state', '=', 'countries_states.state_id');
    })
    ->where('orders_items.order_id', '=', $order->order_id)
    ->get();
```

Comment: paste whole method code please because it looks like something is wrong with the syntax somewhere else.

Comment: static public function fop($order) {
 $players = DB::table('orders_items')
    ->join('users', function ($join) use ($order) {
        $join->on('users.user_id', '=', 'orders_items.user_id')
        $join->on('users.state', '=', 'countries_states.state_id');
    })
    ->where('orders_items.order_id', '=', $order->order_id)
    ->get();

 return $players;

 }

Comment: I see now. You forgot about `;` after `$join->on('users.user_id', '=', 'orders_items.user_id')` :)